# Storing and retreiving high scores

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm working on a Pong game to lean some iPhone programming.

I have an NSString* playerName and int playerScore.

I get this when the game is over.

Now I need a way to store high scores on the user's device.
However there are a couple caveats.

I only bother to store a score if it is a top 10 high score.
And if the user's name is already in the list and the score is worth adding (eg > 10th score), the score is updated and the list s resorted by score.

I'm coming from C++ world.

In C++, I would use a simple file that I would parse, work with in memory, then rewrite the file.

What I would like to know though, is how this should be done in Obj-C. Is there a class or something that makes this sort of task simple and convenient?

Thanks

Comment: hm.. even i'd like to know if there is a class to make this task simple but when i did this, i used a plist file to which i'd read/write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` instances where the dictionaries contain your scores (as `NSNumber`s) and names. Then you can directly read and write this to disk (as a property list) using `initWithContentsOfFile:` and `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create an `NSMutableArray` that will store user scores.
Every time the game ends find the score in the `NSMutableArray` that has the 10 highest value.
After that store both `PlayerName` and `HighestScores` using `NSUserDefaults`

`NSUserDefaults` will allow you to save objects in the user's device

```
NSString *PlayerName;
int PlayerScore;


//SAVING

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:PlayerName forKey:@"name"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:PlayerScore forKey:@"score"];

//GETTING

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"name"];

// getting an NSInteger
int myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"score"];
```

This is just some guide I think will help :)